# Problem on update an order tax line Woocommerce Rest API v3

Tags: woocommerce

I've tried to edit an order tax lines. I get problems while:

Trying to remove a single tax line:

```
"data": {
    "tax_lines": [
         {
             "id" : 1,
             "rate_id" : null
         }
    ]
 }
```

Emptying the tax lines:

```
"data": {
    "tax_lines": [ ] 
}
```

or

```
"data": {
    "tax_lines": null   
}
```

I'm using the latest version of the Woo Rest Api.

Nothing's happening. What should I do?

Comment: What kind of problems?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to update an order by using postman like this https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#update-an-order,
i passed the data via postman and send it to my custom endpoint, the update returns 200 but the tax_lines wasn't remove